# Twilio Taskrouter: How do I configure my JS client (Worker) to receive voice calls after a reservation has been accepted?

Tags: python, twilio

I am referring to the example code [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/taskrouter/agent-ui-add-project).

I am able to get the client running, task is assigned and reservation created and accepted as well. But then the call is not connected and the client keeps listening the default waiting tune.
I have tried `reservation.dequeue()` and `reservation.call()` but to no avail.

I am using Python-flask and twilio library 6.3.0.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you trying to answer the phone call from within the agent interface?

Comment: @philnash Yes, I am trying to receive the call from agent interface. I am also trying to figure out if we need the **twilio.client** sdk for the client along with **taskrouter** sdk, as device controls are available in **twilio.client** sdk. And if so, how would I integrate _clientToken_ and _workerToken_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From the comments, you are looking to answer this call within the browser.

You do need to include the [Twilio Client JS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js) for this, alongside the [TaskRouter JS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/worker-js). Check out the quick start on using [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/client/javascript#download-configure-and-run-the-starter-app) to get familiar with it.

In order to connect up TaskRouter and Twilio Client you don't need to combine the tokens. What you do need to do is set your [worker](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/workers)'s `contact_uri` attribute to `"client:" + YOUR_CLIENTS_NAME` (for example `{ "contact_uri": "client:Bob" }`).

Then when your worker [dequeues the assignment](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/taskrouter/worker-js#reservation-dequeue), Twilio will look at the worker's `contact_uri` address and route the call there.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Sweet! Would you mind marking this answer as correct so that others can see that it helped too? Thanks.